# SharePoint custom field control intermittently reverts back to text field

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2007, field, sharepoint-api

This is maybe a long shot, but I have a custom field control that renders a colorpicker field for a custom SharePoint list. The field control inherits from the BaseFieldControl.

Most of the time everything works fine, but every now and then the control will revert back to a normal text field within the list. (Possible reverting to the Parent BaseField) This happens on the edit item page.

Something else we noticed is that every time this happens the labels for the fields will display the resouce location instead of the resource value. For example it will display

$Resources:CT_Banner_Name;

Instead of the actual value in the resource.resx file.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when I see the $Resources: it's a clear indicator that a feature is missing on one of the load balanced servers.  Maybe your custom control references an absolute url or server directly which may cause certain requests to fail?

Comment: Thanks UJ, this was actually for a single server, and feature was installed and activated for the site (including the associated resource.resx file).

Comment: We managed to find the error though. Using SharePoint Manager we discovered that a couple of custom lists had corrupted schema files for the fields (The lists field instances). I'm not sure how this happened though. The content type seems fine. It's almost as the lists disconnected itself from the feature and didn't update anymore. But grabbing a working schema and replacing the broken fields' seemed to have fixed it.